# Unlock and wakeup from progressive/installable web app for building calling app

Tags: webrtc, progressive-web-apps, push-api

I am at the moment researching about the new features of progressive web apps and they are pretty amazing and allow building web apps which are feeling very native. In particular, I'm considering at the moment to build a purely web based, installable calling app. Most features for something like that exist already:

- Audio and video calls are very simple to do with WebRTC.
- Using service workers and the push API, it is possible to send push notifications to a web app which is not even opened currently: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Push_API
- Web apps are becoming installable and can add themselves to your home screen: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Progressive/Installable

Nevertheless, for building a serious calling app working on a mobile phone, **it is necessary to be able to unlock/wakeup the screen of the phone in case of an incoming call**. I unfortunately couldn't find anything out about a possibility for doing that; even not with features which are at the moment still considered as "experimental". Does anybody know if it is possible to do that at the moment, just using web technologies? And if not, if in the near future there are plans in browser technologies to allow something like that?

In my opinion, this is something which should be possible (at least in the future), since this would enable developers to build progressive web apps which are having more features and are even closer to native apps.

Comment: Well, it seems that this question of yours is not yet possible as of now, you can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/) of progressive web apps the only possible way that you can do with it. If you want to know if this will be possible in the near future, just check the documentation link to know the updates on it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API that fit your requirement, the best thing you can do is to send notification continuously when someone call you (which I have seen in many other apps).

The most recently feature a web page can do when the phone is sleeping is to play background music or control the volume ([MediaSession](https://wicg.github.io/mediasession/)). But that is only in experiment stage.

I'm not sure allowing a webpage to "wake up" the phone from sleeping state is a good idea. The web move forward but there are things that *should be* handled by native apps.